# How does this definition of Fourier transform in Fulton and Harris 3.32 relate to the usual notion of Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, fourier-series

This is exercise 3.32 in Fulton and Harris' *Representation Theory: A First Course*.

[image: Fulton and Harris 3.32]

It defines *Fourier transform* in a form unfamiliar to me, and I could not find any definition of Fourier transform like this after searching on the Internet. How does Fulton and Harris' definition relate to the familiar definition of Fourier series or Fourier transform (sources: [Wikipedia entry for Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series), [Wikipedia entry for Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)) as following?

Fourier series:

$$
s(x) \sim A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(A_n \cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{P} \right) + B_n \sin\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{P}\right)\right) 
$$

Fourier transform:

$$
\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\ e^{-i 2\pi \xi x}\,dx
$$

For additional reference, the definition of a *representation* can also be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation).

Comment: This is a nice question. I don't have time to write a full answer now, but for Fourier series the group $G$ is the circle group and for the fourier transform (as written here) the group $G$ is the additive group $\mathbb{R}$. So in both cases $1/|G|$ does not make a whole lot of sense and sums should be replaced by integrals. But then your last formula resembles the one in F&H with  $x= g$ and $\rho(g) = \exp(-i 2\pi xi g)$. The point is that for every $\xi$ there is a map $\rho: G = \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}^* = GL(V_\rho)$ (where $V_\rho = \mathbb{C}$) given by $x \mapsto \exp(-2i \pi x)$...

Comment: ...and this map $\rho$ defines a *representation* of the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ on the 1-dimensional vectorspace $V_\rho = \mathbb{C}$ which in this case just means that $\rho(x + y) = \rho(x)\rho(y)$, a famous property of exponentials

Comment: sorry, In my first comment I typed xi instead of $\xi$. This was a typo. The $xi$ together is one symbol, not the product of $i$ and $x$, because $x$ is called $g$ there and hence does not appear. Unfortunately it is too late to edit now

Answer (score 2):

This is a long story. This is the [Fourier transform on a finite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_on_finite_groups). It's a generalization of the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), which it specializes to when $G = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The sense in which the discrete Fourier transform deserves the name "Fourier transform" (aside from satisfying an inversion formula, a Plancherel formula, etc.) is that it is a special case of the [Fourier transform on locally compact abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Pontryagin_duality_and_the_Fourier_transform), which relate functions on such a group $A$ to functions on its [Pontryagin dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#The_Pontryagin_duality_theorem) $\widehat{A}$, which can be identified with its irreducible representations. This version of the Fourier transform specializes to Fourier series when $A = S^1$ and to the usual Fourier transform when $A = \mathbb{R}$.

So, this is a generalization of a special case of a generalization of the usual Fourier transform, to a not-necessarily-abelian but finite group. It has a generalization to compact groups via the [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem), although I think most people wouldn't call that a Fourier transform. The case of nonabelian and noncompact groups is very complicated and I don't know anything about it, but it's studied in [harmonic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_analysis#Abstract_harmonic_analysis).

For the finite group case you can see, for example, Terras' *[Fourier Analysis on Finite Groups and Applications](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/fourier-analysis-on-finite-groups-and-applications/8662B523E28C44A6F245AB50A2B06EBD)*.